# jest test:coverage with react propTypes / defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-proptypes

I have a dumb component, with few props I'm passing. I'm also using PropTypes.

When I run jest test:coverage, it shows me % Funcs 100.
However, when I add defaultProps, test:coverage for % Funcs drops to 50.

Is there any way to test defaultProps or alternatively exclude these from test:coverage chyeck/report?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach, should be using this line **istanbul ignore next** above the defaultProps statement:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
DetailPage.defaultProps = {
  metaData: null
};
```

Comment: nice suggestion. however, I don't really want to add this flag in every component to ignore default props... can it be set up globally?

Comment: Yes that's kind of tedious I used to put that line on the mapStateToProps redux function that I didn't need to test, your case is weird because in that project I never got any coverage issues with the default props statements.

Comment: yeah, seems quite odd to me... having defaultProps should really not affect test coverage... I managed to create a workaround (please see my answer). But it's really not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an ongoing issue with istanbul, there are workarounds (like the one suggested by @jean182 ). However, I'd like to avoid excluding defaultProps from instabul coverage in every file...

I managed to get 100% Funcs coverage by testing defaultProps like this:

```
WidgetHeader.defaultProps = {
    title: '',
    subtitle: '',
    lastUpdated: '',
    onUpdateClick: () => {}
};
```

then added test for it:

```
it( 'should check defaultProps', () => {
    const component = mount( <WidgetHeader /> );

    const props = component.props();

    expect( props.title ).toEqual( '' );
    expect( props.subtitle ).toEqual( '' );
    expect( props.lastUpdated ).toEqual( '' );
    expect( props.onUpdateClick ).not.toThrow();
});
```

Still not 100% if this is the correct approach. Testing defaultProps for each component seems tedious...
Anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks